# Need help controlling a path in python

Tags: python, ftp

I've to implement a FTP server for university assignemnt. I'm struggling to implement the CWD function.
A path is passed to my function. This path can be relative and absolute. I have a var containing the absolute path of the current working directory. Can You help me in doing every needed legality check on the passed path?
This is what I've coded so far

```
    def CWD(self, new_path):
    if self.logged:
        if new_path[0] != '/':
            new_path = self.current_wd+'/'+new_path
            if  os.path.exists(new_path) and os.path.isdir(new_path) and self.users_dict[self.cur_user][1] in new_path:
                self.current_wd = new_path
                os.chdir(self.current_wd)
                self.communicate_to_client('250 Requested file action okay, completed (relpath).')
            else:
                self.communicate_to_client('550 Requested action not taken (relpath).')
        elif new_path in self.current_wd and self.users_dict[self.cur_user][1] in new_path:
            self.current_wd = new_path
            os.chdir(self.current_wd)
            self.control_socket.send('250 Requested file action okay, completed.\r\n')
        elif os.path.exists(new_path) and os.path.isdir(new_path) and self.users_dict[self.cur_user][1] in new_path:
            self.current_wd = os.path.join(self.current_wd, new_path)
            os.chdir(self.current_wd)
            self.control_socket.send('250 Requested file action okay, completed.\r\n')
        else:
            self.control_socket.send('550 Requested action not taken in CWD.\r\n')
    elif not self.logged and self.cur_user != '':
        self.communicate_to_client('531 Insert password to take this operation')
    else:
        self.communicate_to_client('530 Authentication needed')
```

Comment: Why are you changing the CWD if you're storing the path in the class? This will break virtual roots.

Comment: I need to change the current working directory to let the client navigates in his sub-tree of the filesystem.

Comment: But there's no reason why you can't just specify the path in the appropriate function calls.

Comment: I'm not understanding what are you trying to tell me. Please try with other words